# About the torque of mini servo motor

Tags: servo, torque

I'd like to automate button pressing on Nintendo DSi for a certain purpose.

For this, I think I will use a raspberry pi and a mini servo motor SG-90.

My question is, would the SG-90 would give enough torque to be able to press the button?

The following figures are provided :

Couple: 1,6 kg.cm at 4.8V

Speed: 0,12 s/60° (probably also at 4.8V)

Thank you

Comment: Give the same data for the button you want to press! More obviously, yes of course you could press a button because you'd need some sort of lever or screw to do so could get torque multiplication. You need to decide how a servo with 180 deg rotation would actually press your button, what size lever you need, what length of travel etc etc.

Comment: I have a design in my mind, I just wanted to make sure it wasn't a ridiculous idea :)
Thank you @JackCreasey

Comment: Sounds like you want to create some type physical [macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_(computer_science)) device ;) Cheating in video games, potentially.

Comment: "Couple: 1,6 kg.cm at 4.8V" - servo specs are often 'optimistic'. Expect <1kg.cm in practice. http://www.teaser.fr/~osegouin/aeromode/servos.phtml

Comment: The usual motor that closes a switch, called a 'relay', is available and inexpensive; why use a servomotor instead?

Comment: @KingDuken It is. Though, since I can't play it online, it is only for my pleasure :)

Comment: @user167987 I'm not judging haha. You do you.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I should've seen that... I kind of thought the servo motors I used are too weak to be around 1kg.cm or more.
But I hope the servo motors to put too much force into the button or anything. I will have to test myself since I don't have any spec on buttons. Thank you

Comment: @Whit3rd It came to my mind but isn't normal DC motors are difficult to control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the linear displacement of the switch and required maximum slew rate and thus toggle frequency.

The torque is 2.2kg-cm or 22kg-mm is enough to damage the switch so spring load force is not likely an issue.

Response time of 120ms is slow for 60 deg. But for 20 deg it may be 40ms or more.

What is needed to create say 3mm linear displacement in 20 deg rotation at some radius?

One approach is the design of a friction roller Cam on the servo arm.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find the specification for the switch or any sort. Or I didn't spend enough time. Thank you, Tony. I will look into what you said.